# replace the date with macro in word 2007/ replace part of number with superscript

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, superscript

I need help to change the format of the date in some doc files. I have hundreds of pages in which i make a replace for different dates in romanian, actually i need to replace only the slash before the date, is there a simpler way to do it? a macro for replacing all the dates like this

Something like:

```
"nr. 313/17 noiembrie 2011" i have to replace it with "nr. 313 din 17 noiembrie 2011"

"15/3 aprilie 2012" -> "15 din 3 aprilie 2012"

"27/03 aprilie 2012" -> "27 din 03 aprilie 2012"
```

i have to replace the slash "/" between the numbers with the word "din" (with spaces before and after)

II. i also have to be carefull with the replace because i have other formats in the text like "art. 385/15" in which the slash should not be replaced with the word "din"

this is another problem that i have not found an answer for:

```
                
"art. 15/2" - "art. 152"

"art. 27/12" - "art. 2712"

"art. 385/19" - "art. 38519"
```

- the "/2", "/12", "/19" must be replaced only with superscript and the slash must be removed, i have many articles like this in text that i have to replace ... and a macro could help me work faster and better

Is there any way to solve the 2 problems? (i use word 2007 and 2010)

Answer (score 1):

The OP asks to change date strings of the form "15/3 aprilie" to "15 din 3 aprilie", without affecting other cases of [number/number]. This can be done with a wildcard search-and-replace operation, which is run 12 times for each of the 12 months.

The core routine, containing the single search-and-replace operation, follows here:

```
     Sub replacemonth(month As String)

            With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = "([0-9]{1,3})/([0-9]{1,3} " + month + ")"
                .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                .Replacement.Text = "\1 din \2"
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindStop
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = True
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With

    End Sub
```

And then this second routine runs the routine for each of the months:

```
 Sub ReplaceDates()
       replacemonth ("ianuarie")
       replacemonth ("februarie")
       replacemonth ("martie")
       replacemonth ("aprilie")
       replacemonth ("mai")
       replacemonth ("iunie")
       replacemonth ("iulie")
       replacemonth ("august")
       replacemonth ("septembrie")
       replacemonth ("octombrie")
       replacemonth ("noiembrie")
       replacemonth ("decembrie")
End Sub
```

Put both of those into your macro editor, run the second macro (ReplaceDates), and it should replace all of the dates as you've specified.

The search routine assumes that the numbers on either side of the slash can be up to three digits long (as in the first example in the original post); that number can be easily changed as needed in the search string.